# How to temporarily override import behavior?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-import

I am using a module, `module_1`, that is able to use `module_2` if it is installed on the system, but falls back on other implementation if it is not. The way it checks if `module_2` is:

```
# module_1.__init__.py

try:
    import module_2
    _MODULE2 = True
except ImportError:
    _MODULE2 = False
```

I have `module_2` installed in the same environment but I don't want `module_1` to use it.

Is there a way to `import module_1` but override the `import` mechanism to make the `import` of `module_2` specifically raise an `ImportError`?

What I've tried:

```
import sys
class hide_module_2:
    def __enter__(self):
        class HideModule2(dict):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                self.update(*args, **kwargs)

            def __getitem__(self, key):
                if key == 'module_2':
                    raise ImportError('Module 2 de')
                super().__getitem__(key)
        sys.modules = NoPandas(**sys.modules)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        # revert to regular dictionary
        sys.modules = dict(**sys.modules)

with hide_module_2():
    import module_1
```

I thought this would work since `sys.modules` is a dictionary of currently `import`ed modules and I thought it would be referenced in the `import`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to devise a sort of hacky solution since the import system throws an ImportError if something is imported and sys.modules has a `None` in it:

```
class hide_module_2:   
    def __enter__(self):
        self.module_2 = sys.modules.get('module_2')
        sys.modules['module_2'] = None

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if self.module_2 is None:
          sys.modules.pop('module_2')
        else:
          sys.modules['module_2'] = self.module_2

with hide_module_2():
    import module_1
```